# can't fix this error. CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Character

Tags: c#

New and learning c# don't understand and can't fix this error.  CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Character' because 'Character' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

my character code is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ConsoleTestRpg.Items.Interfaces;

namespace ConsoleTestRpg.Enties.Models
{
    public class Character
    {
        public string? Name;
        public int Level;
        public Attributes Attributes;
        public int Gold;
        public string? Background;
        public int Inventoryweight;
        public int Exp;
        public int MaxExp;
        public List<string>? AdventuresPlayed;
        public bool IsAlive;
        public int ArmorClass;
        public List<IItem>? Inventory;
        public int HitPoints;
        public int MaxHitPoints;
        public int MagicPoints;
        public int MaxMagicPoints;
        public CharacterClass Class;

        public int Count()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Attributes
    {
        public int Strength;
        public int MaxStrength;
        public int Constitution;
        public int MaxConstitution;
        public int MaxDexterity;
        public int Dexterity;
        public int Intelligence;
        public int MaxIntelligence;
        public int Wisdom;
        public int MaxWisdom;
        public int Charisma;
        public int MaxCharisma;

    }
     public enum CharacterClass
    {
        Fighter,
        Thief,
        Mage,
        Cleric
    }
}
```

the code in question is:

```
using ConsoleTestRpg.Adventures;
using ConsoleTestRpg.Adventures.interfaces;
using ConsoleTestRpg.Enties.Models;
using ConsoleTestRpg.Entites.Interfaces;

namespace ConsoleTestRpg.Game
{
    public class GameService
    {
        private IAdventureService adventureService;
        private CharacterService characterService;

        public GameService(IAdventureService AdventureService, ICharacterService CharacterService)
        {
            adventureService = AdventureService;
            characterService = CharacterService;
        }
        public bool StartGame(Adventure adventure = null)
        {

            try
            {
                if (adventure == null)
                {
                    adventure = adventureService.GetInitialAdventure();
                }
                

                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine();

                //Create Title Banner
                for (int i = 0; i <= adventure.Title.Length + 3; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                    if(i == adventure.Title.Length + 3)
                    {
                        Console.Write("\n");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"| {adventure.Title} |");
                for (int i = 0; i <= adventure.Title.Length + 3; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                    if (i == adventure.Title.Length + 3)
                    {
                        Console.Write("\n");
                    }
                }

                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
                Console.WriteLine($"\n{adventure.Description.ToUpper()}");

                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;

                var charactersInRange = characterService.GetCharactersInRange(adventure.MinimumLevel, adventure.MaxLevel);

                if (charactersInRange.Count() == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No characters in range of adventure");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("WHO DOTH WISH TO CHANCE DEATH?");
                    var characterCount = 0;
                    foreach (var character in charactersInRange)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"#{characterCount} {character.Name} Level - {character.Level} {character.Class}");
                        characterCount++;
                    }
                }

                return true;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Something went wrong {ex.Message}");
                return true;
```

I've looked online and the docs... but can't figure it out. maybe I'm just not understanding what I am looking at.

the GetcharacterInRange code:

```
 public List<Character> GetCharactersInRange(int minLevel = 0, int 
maxLevel = 20)
    {
        var basePath = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}characters";
        var charactersInRange = new List<Character>();

        try
        {
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(basePath);
            foreach (var file in directory.GetFiles($"*.json"))
            {
                using (StreamReader fi = File.OpenText(file.FullName))
                {
                    var potentialCharacterInRange = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Character>(fi.ReadToEnd());
                    if (potentialCharacterInRange.IsAlive && (potentialCharacterInRange.Level >= minLevel && potentialCharacterInRange.Level <= maxLevel))
                    {
                        charactersInRange.Add(potentialCharacterInRange);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine($" Something went wrong {ex.Message}");
        }
        return charactersInRange;

    }

    Character ICharacterService.GetCharactersInRange(int minLevel, int maxLevel)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Comment: Which line in the code has error?

Comment: What is the data type of `charactersInRange`? It looks like you think it is `List<Character>` or `Character[]` but the error message suggests that it is just `Character`. I suspect that your `GetCharactersInRange` method is incorrectly implemented.

Comment: @chetan foreach (var character in charactersInRange) is the line.

Comment: @jimcilhinney i believe a list of created characters. I'm following a video series to learn c#

Comment: please don't use `var`. it occludes information from us and makes it harder for us to understand your code. We don't have your solution loaded into an IDE

Comment: so remove the vars?

Comment: I know you believe that, as evidenced by how you're using it, but you need to actually look to see if what you believe is true. The error message suggests that it's not.

Comment: "so remove the vars?" exchange them for the real data types. Your IDE (Visual Studio may be ) will tell you. Hoover with the mouse over it

Comment: The fact that you have a `Count` method that is not implemented is also suspicious. I suspect that you added that because you saw an error elsewhere when you tried to call `Count` but you hid the problem instead of fixing it.

Comment: what's is being returned from `GetCharactersInRange` method? I believe it is not a collection of characters.

Comment: @jmcilhinney what do you mean? what i did was not a fix?

Comment: I mean that you tried to use `charactersInRange.Count()` and you were told that no such method existed so, instead of addressing the actual problem, i.e. `charactersInRange` was the wrong type, you just added a method with that name that didn't actually do anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you do this:

```cs
var charactersInRange = characterService.GetCharactersInRange(adventure.MinimumLevel, adventure.MaxLevel);
```

you think that you're calling this method:

```cs
public List<Character> GetCharactersInRange(int minLevel = 0, int maxLevel = 20)
```

but you're actually calling this method:

```cs
Character ICharacterService.GetCharactersInRange(int minLevel, int maxLevel)
```

That's because you have declared `characterService` as type `ICharacterService`:

```cs
private ICharacterService characterService;
```

so the explicit implement is the one that gets invoked.

What almost certainly should be the case is that the `GetCharactersInRange` method declare in the `ICharacterService` interface should have a return type of `List<Character>` rather than just `Character`. How does it make sense to have a method whose name explicitly states that it's getting multiple `Character` objects have a return type that explicitly permits only one? Your service class could then just implement that method instead of having two method with the same name and different return types. Your `GameService` code would then be calling that one and only method with the correct return type.

Comment: This is what is in the icharacterService.  public Character GetCharactersInRange(int minLevel = 0, int maxLevel = 20);

Comment: @Syziel, and I've told you why that's wrong and what to do about it. Now you need to do it.

Comment: i did also i removed I from private CharacterService characterService; and that seemed to have solved my problem. thank you jmcilhinney